# Expandible Multiselect Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How can I get an expandable [tree view] multiselect dropdown list?

For example, from the below snapshot, if I have sub-list for Animals [Cat, Cow etc] is there any plugin as such that would show a + sign and when clicked, it would show the sub-list in the same dropdown like a tree view?

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: I doubt a plugin for that exists, it shouldn't be too hard to implement yourself

Comment: I agree. JQueryUI have it. YUI have it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a select tag alone, I know you can't. In your case, you need to create a customized select box.

- This can be done using a combination of html tags, just like the [treeview](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) plugin of JavaScript library like [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). But you commented to @Edgar  that there is no multi-select for that.
- Also embedding a flash or a java plugins can be a solution.

I guess my examples solution didn't give you the exact thing you wanted. I'll just give a simple example that could be a help to answer your question. This is to create a customized select box.

**Customized Select Box**

How to create the customized select box:

1. Create a div that will be a container of the list.

   `<div id="treeSelect">`
2. Add style on the div that will behave like a select box.

   `#treeSelect{height: 100px;width:  150px;border: 1px solid #000;overflow: auto;}`
3. Add the content of the main list along with the sublist on the div. Include all possible style that could be use to format the content to be more like a tree view list.

   ```
   <span class="mainList">All</span>
   <br />
   <span class="expand" onClick="expand('animals', this);">[+]</span><span class="mainList">Animals</span>
   <br />  
   <ul id="animals" class="subList">
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="Cat">Cat</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="Cow">Cow</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="Cat">Dog</li>
   </ul>
   ```
4. Add a script that will handle how to view the sublist.

   function expand(list, view){

   ```
   var listElement = document.getElementById(list);
   var defaultView = '[+]';

   if(view.innerHTML == defaultView){
       listElement.style.display = "block";
       view.innerHTML = '[-]'; 
   } else {
       listElement.style.display = "none";
       view.innerHTML = '[+]';
   }
   ```

   }

I cannot put all the code so please see the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vef3f/) for the complete code.

I know this is not the exact things you wanted, but I guess it is close to what you need. You can change the style based on your taste and needs. I hope this can be a help and give you idea how to solve your question.

Comment: This is similar to what I am looking! But with one issue where I can't select the parent element. I guess JS Tree plugin is the way to go....but I don't like check boxes, I'd rather have them like a multi-select list!

Comment: With some modification and additional CSS & JS you can get what looks you wanted.I did not make it similar as you wanted, because there a lot of things todo.With the parent you can also add a checkbox to it.I know you'll gonna ask about the checkbox,but I don't have a time to make it like a multi-select.You can customized this by hiding the checkbox then add `onClick` event on `li` that will be the one to check and unchecked it.You also change `li` background if it is selected or not.Again there's still a lot of things to do,but this is a good start.I hope you manage can the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [treeview plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) or the [jsTree plugin](http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/5_others.html)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: But what I am looking for is purely a MULTI-SELECT dropdown list. Ideally, I could I have a child dropdown and show the corresponding sub-list, but wanted to avoid that providing the ability like a tree view that is selectable!

Comment: You could create/deletes some hiddens when the user clicks a node in this plugins. I don't know any built-control that is exactly a multiselect with the features you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<optgroup>` for each main category whose children are hidden by default, and when clicking on the `<optgroup>` label it can simply unhide the child `<option>`(s).

Something like the following:

In your CSS:

```
#categories optgroup option { display: none; }
```

In your HTML:

```
<select name="categories" id="categories">
    <optgroup label="+ Animals">
        <option value="bird">Bird</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

In your JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$('#categories > optgroup').click(function(){
    $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

Comment: and when I try to select the sub-list elements it just toggles!

Comment: @HonorGod Ah it seems it's been too long since I've used optgroups, they just aren't really accessible via CSS so that's probably not going to work then. You're better off using something like the treeview plugin or jsTree plugin mentioned and simply styling that tree to *look* like a multi-select, but simply bind the actions to change the form values when clicked.